# Websphere MQ Message and ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, ibm-mq

I have to read from and write to a Websphere MQ Message queue. I'm using ZF2 with Doctrine in my project. What is the best approach and are there some tutorials where I can have some inspirations? Does ZF2 has some predefined services to talk with MQ? Thank you for any help...

Comment: Does anyone has some expierence with MQ and ZF2?